# Unable to fetch POST request in Azure devops Agentless invoke REST API

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have created POST API request in azure invoking service, Request is failing and showing error like

> Specified value has invalid HTTP Header characters

REST API example : POST /

Header:

```
{
"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
"Authorization:":"$(system.Authorization)"
}
```

Body(in json format) :

```
{
"grant_type":"client_credentials"
}
```

Comment: Which service are you invoking?

Comment: pipeline-Agentless job -RST API